# Render a layer on top of a graphics context

Tags: ios, core-graphics

In core Graphics, I am hoping to be able to draw updates to a UIView *without having to redraw the entire image each time.*  The initial image is drawn from a CGImageRef:

```
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctxImage);
CGContextDrawImage(context, _screenRect, image);
```

Initially I was adding the new sections to an off screen context with the 'full image' and then creating a new CGImageRef from it before re-drawing.

```
CGContextDrawImage(tmp_Context,targetRect,_section);
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(tmp_Context);
CGContextDrawImage(context, _screenRect, image);
```

The problem with this is that in every frame update I need to redraw the entire image to the screen rather than somehow superimposing just the sections. This would yield a large performance increase if possible but not sure how to go about it. Possibly with CGLayer?

edit:  I have been trying to rapidly update the view in a for loop as I receive small sections, the problem is drawRect isn't getting called to do any updates maybe because the for loop is going too fast and continually interrupting previous calls?

```
drawLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(ctxImage, targetRect.size, nil);
                layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(drawLayer);
                CGContextDrawImage(layerContext,targetRect,ipegSection);

                CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(currentScreen, targetRect.origin, drawLayer);
// Update the UI
                [targetView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: Can you tell about what are thoses sections, give a screenshot of what you try to do ? I just don't get what you are drawing and why.

Comment: the sections are small parts of a larger image that contain movement. I have a MJPeg decoder that works by receiving those sections and decoding them rather than full images on every frame. We take that movement and superimpose it on the original image on each frame.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do (?) :

```
CGContextDrawImage(context, targetRect, _section);
```

Like this you draw only your section on the current context, not draw it on another context then redraw the screen entirely.

Comment: Aye this makes sense but not working for me.. do I need to call drawRect on the view to get anything to update?